# Migrate one MS SQL database to another

Tags: sql-server

Could you please suggest the easiest way to programmatically (not via UI) generate a script to migrate specific tables (schema, constraints, indexes) to another database on a separate server.

I am aware of replication, SSIS, generate scripts feature, backup-restore approach and SQL Import/export window. However, all these approaches require at least some kind of UI interaction or don' allow to copy constraints or don't allow to migrate only part of data.

Database where I will be putting the data will be in sync with main DB, so it is possible to just wipe-off existing data in it and overwrite with schema and data from main DB.

Comment: There are so many options it's hard to pin-point what you're actually looking for. Some of the options you've listed also do not necessarily require GUI either. ie. backup/restore. One other option I'd like to throw out there is PowerShell and SMO. See here. http://www.sqlhammer.com/blog/scripting-objects-with-powershell/

Comment: restore-backup is something that we currently use, but now we need to use servers of different versions (express on replicas) and also need to migrate only part of the data, as express is limited in size.

Comment: generate the backup file restore your server then rename DB name

Comment: @tinka, not sure that I understood your idea. there's no problem to backup-restore as such. the problem is that I want to pass only part of data to replica. backup-restore only allows to make a full backup. I cannot afford the approach of restoring another gigantic DB on the server just for the sake of removing unnecessary data and backing it up again to pass on replica. This is very resource consuming.

Comment: @ninjaboy then we can generate script with `schema only` which is only script nothing else you can run your new server

Comment: @tinka, I need to migrate only part of DB: specific tables with their foreign key/primary key constraints, indexes AND data from these tables.

Answer (score 1):

From Comment: *I need to migrate only part of DB: specific tables with their foreign key/primary key constraints, indexes AND data from these tables*

as per my understanding i hope this will help you

[image: Right Click ON DB]

Click Next
[image]

Choose your Location
[image]
USE DATABASE: FALSE will help you to execute script in your New DB which you created in your new server *basically it will not generate Create DB script*

[image]

Read carefully Table View/Option whatever you need please make it true

[image]

Click Next Pickup script file from your location and run on your new server

Comment: yes, this could help in case if I could do this exercise programmatically

Comment: At the moment I have found something called SMO which can potentially be helpful but then again it has strict dependency on the version of sql installed which introdcues complexity in my case as we use 2008 and 2008R2 servers which means that i will need to  create separate build for different DB versions

Comment: @ninjaboy every script generator provide the facility to backward compatibility, in 4th images of this answer `Script for Server Version` we can select from `2012 to 2005` but your problem is solved and it great :)

Comment: Well. It is not solved yet as smo is not supported by sql2000. 2000 used mechanism called DMO whih means that i will need to inplement two versions of the same functionality using different approaches. So i am still looking

Comment: @ninjaboy Sorry i have just checked it `Script for Server Version` soppurt `2000` also

Comment: could you please share the link?

Comment: @ninjaboy no need any link see the 4th image of this answer there are one option `Script for Server Version` where you can select `server version 2000` and create your script with `2000 version` compitability

Comment: there are two points of misunderstanding I guess:
1. I need to do all this programmatically, i.e. not by clicking mouse or interacting with UI anyhow. This has to be a script or a program, preferrably in .net
2. I have to support process of syncing data from sql v2000 to sql v2000, from sql 2008 to sql 2008, from sql 2008 to sql 2000. And it highly desirable to avoid implementing custom solution for each of the variants above.