# how to copy a database in SQL server management studios

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database in SQL server management studio named wardobsliveisle. I want to create another database in SQL server management studio that is the exact same copy of wardobsliveisle but I want to call it demosql. How do I do this?

Comment: `BACKUP` wardobsliveisle DB , `RESTORE` it using new name and back to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990606

Comment: SSMS even has a Copy Wizard, did you try it?

Comment: *Why* do you want this copy? If you want a read-only replica you can create a snapshot of the original database, which is instantaneous and only allocates space when data pages in the original database change.

Comment: I just want a copy for demo purposes so can you explain how i do this?

Comment: You need to run the `CREATE SNAPSHOT` statement as shown in [Create a Database Snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx), specifying the snapshot name and file. You can connect to the snapshot as if it were another database. The file will be empty initially. Each time a page is modified in the original database, the original data will be copied to the snapshot file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have database `wardobsliveisle` in SSMS and now you want to create an other database `demosql` from `wardobsliveisle`. The process given below creates a copy of `wardobsliveisle` with new name `demosql`. This new database has now separate `.ldf` and `.mdf` files and it is absolutely a separate copy of your original database.

Follow the steps

1. Right click on `Databases` in your `Object Explorer` in SSMS.
2. Select `Restore Files and Filegroups...`, a wizard opens
3. Type a new database name `demosql` in `To Database` box and select source
   database **(Not a backup file)** from `From Database` dropdown.
4. Click `OK` button

It will take a few minutes or less.

Comment: This will restore an existing backup, *not* copy a database. A separate Copy Database wizard already exists under `Tasks`

Comment: so how would you carry out my question if the above example is wrong. As i am new to this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I modified the answer for your understanding. This process doesn't use `Existing Backup`.

Comment: Thank you lali. Worked in the end

Answer (score 0):

Taken from MSDN:

**General Steps for Using Backup and Restore to Copy a Database**

When you use backup and restore to copy a database to another instance of SQL Server, the source and destination computers can be any platform on which SQL Server runs.

The general steps are:
Back up the source database, which can reside on an instance of SQL Server 2005 or later. The computer on which this instance of SQL Server is running is the source computer.

On the computer to which you want to copy the database (the destination computer), connect to the instance of SQL Server on which you plan to restore the database. If needed, on the destination server instance, create the same backup devices as used to the backup of the source databases.

Restore the backup of the source database on the destination computer. Restoring the database automatically creates all of the database files.

The following topics address additional considerations that may affect this process.

**Before You Restore Database Files**

Restoring a database automatically creates the database files that are needed by the restoring database. By default, the files that are created by SQL Server during the restoration process use the same names and paths as the backup files from the original database on the source computer.

Optionally, when restoring the database, you can specify the device mapping, file names, or path for the restoring database. This might be necessary in the following situations:

The directory structure or drive mapping used by the database on the original computer not exist on the other computer. For example, perhaps the backup contains a file that would be restored to drive E by default, but the destination computer lacks a drive E.

The target location might have insufficient space.

You are reusing a database name that exists on the restore destination and any of its files is named the same as a database file in the backup set, one of the following occurs:

If the existing database file can be overwritten, it will be overwritten (this would not affect a file that belongs to a different database name).

If the existing file cannot be overwritten, a restore error would occur.

To avoid errors and unintended consequences, before the restore operation, you can use the backupfile history table to find out the database and log files in the backup you plan to restore.

**Moving the Database Files**

If the files within the database backup cannot be restored onto the destination computer because of the reasons mentioned earlier, it is necessary to move the files to a new location while they are being restored. For example:
You want to restore a database from backups created in the default location of the earlier version.

It may be necessary to restore some of the database files in the backup to a different drive because of capacity considerations. This is likely to be a common occurrence because most computers within an organization do not have the same number and size of disk drives or identical software configurations.

It may be necessary to create a copy of an existing database on the same computer for testing purposes. In this case, the database files for the original database already exist, so different file names need to be specified when the database copy is created during the restore operation.

For more information, see "To restore files and filegroups to a new location," later in this topic.

**Changing the Database Name**

The name of the database can be changed as it is restored to the destination computer, without having to restore the database first and then change the name manually. For example, it may be necessary to change the database name from Sales to SalesCopy to indicate that this is a copy of a database.

The database name that is explicitly supplied when you restore a database is used automatically as the new database name. Because the database name does not already exist, a new one is created by using the files in the backup.